# How to set a property of an element to contain a function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to assign a function to a custom attribute of a DOM-element. Using jQuery.

.prop(String, function) will not assign the function to the specified property, but will invoke the function and assign its result.

I have an ugly solution:

```
$("#a").prop(
     "customAttr", 
     function() {
         return function() {
             $("#a").text("B");
         };
     }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rapik/fyn6zh85/

Is there any better way to do it (using jQuery)?

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. jQuery properties are supposed to represent information about the elements, not functions to be called on them. Could you share the problem you're really trying to solve, and see if we can propose a better solution?

Comment: My application looks for optional custom attributes that may contain a function which will be invoked if present. Almost like onclick attribute. I was looking for the way to set such an attribute from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm *guessing* that the reason you're trying to associate this function with these objects is so that you can cause the function to be invoked when something specific happens in the application. A better way to do this is to use *events*.

```
// set up the event handler
$("#a").on('somecustomevent', function() { $(this).text("B"); });

// Then, where you want that function to be invoked, trigger it.
$("#a").trigger('somecustomevent');
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking about using .on() but didn't know how to call it later.